# How to do target based encoding in R

Tags: r, encoding, categorical-data

I've a few categorical variables and I'm trying to do a target based encoding on it.
Following is my code

```
str(df)
var1 Factor w/8 levels "1", "2", "3"...
var2 Factor w/5 levels "1", "3", "5"... etc
target Factor w/2 levels "1", "0"
```

I'm trying to convert the levels of these factors to the probability of the event rate hence

```
levels(df$var1) <- table(df$var1, df$target)[,2]/ (table(df$var1, df$target)[,1] + table(df$var1, df$target)[,2])
```

which converts the variables like

```
str(df)
var1 Factor w/8 levels "0.0023", "0.08", "0.09"... etc
```

As i wanted to convert these into numerics, I did an as.numeric conversion

```
df$var1 <- as.numeric(df$var1)
```

But all the values got changed to 1, 2, 3 etc and not the actual probabilities I was looking for i.e. 0.0023, 0.08, 0.09 etc

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
df$var1 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$var1))
```

or

```
df$var1 <- levels(df$Var1)[as.numeric(df$var1)]
```

Comment: That was such a D'oh moment! I think I need a break. Thanx a ton.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped

Comment: `as.numeric(levels(df$Var1))[df$var1]` is recommended and more efficient than `as.numeric(as.character(df$var1))`. For more details see `?factor` (Warning section)

Answer (score 2):

Try `df$var1 <- as.numeric(levels(df$var1))[df$var1]`.
Here is an explanation

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1 = factor(c("0.0023", "0.08", "0.09")))
df2 <- data.frame(var1 = c("0.0023", "0.08", "0.09"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(df1)
str(df2)
# does't work because var1 is factor not character
as.numeric(df1$var1)
# but it works for df2
as.numeric(df2$var1)
# solution to convert type of var1 in df1
as.numeric(levels(df1$var1))[df1$var1]
```